# Jsoup simple parse

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am new to programing and I have been over the Jsoup.org cookbook and stackoverflow over and over, but i can't get my app working. When I try to parse text from website the app crashes. I really don't know where I'm making a mistake.

I want to get this text from html:

```
<div id="noga">
<div>
  <h1>Kontakt</h1>
  Agencija RS za okolje<br />
  Vojkova 1b<br />
  1000 Ljubljana, Slovenija<br />
  Tel: +386 (0)1 4784 000<br />
  Fax: +386 (0)1 4784 052<br />
  <a href="mailto:gp.arso@gov.si">gp.arso@gov.si</a>
</div>
```

And my code in eclipse is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Gumbi2{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/bio.html").get();
        Elements divs = doc.select("div#noga");

        for (Element div : divs)
            System.out.println(div.text());
    } 
}
```

Can someone please help me out and point me in the right direction?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  Since `noga` is an id, you can go after it directly without specifiying `div`.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/bio.html").get();
    Element nogadiv = doc.getElementById("noga").child(0);
    System.out.println(nogadiv);
```

Since you want the contact information, just grab the first child of `noga`.

Comment: still not working - the app chrashes when I hit this button :/ Do I need to do anything else? - reference this to a certain view? Thank you for your anwser!!

Comment: Please give me more information than "the app crashes when I hit this button".  Could you update your post with your latest code?  Exception trace?

Comment: `try {
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/bio.html").get();

         Element nogadiv = doc.getElementById("noga").child(0);

         System.out.println(nogadiv);
         
     } catch (IOException e) {


     }
     setContentView(R.layout.spletnastran);`

Comment: Well now it doesn't crash. In the LogCat I get the output that I wanted i.e. contact data. But the contct data doesn't appear on the screen. Do I need to set some kind of view in the spletnastran.xml layout

Comment: Sorry.. I don't know.  I'm not familiar with the Android API.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me - I think I will get it working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close out the noga div.